# Openssl different intermediates for client and server certs

Tags: ssl, openssl, ca

I am trying to generate a certificate-(authority)-chain, where some intermediates have specific tasks.

There will be a root certificate (skipped for testing) that signs the actual CA, this CA on the one hand, signs a CA that should only be able to sign client-certificates, and on the other hand, signs one/multiple CA's that can only perform server-certificates-signing. The idea is, that this "server-ca" will be deployed into an embedded system in order to create a new server certificate with different sans if nescessary, but should not be able to sign client-certificates. [(see my fine drawing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYcUD.png)

I did not find much about constraining a ca. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/841735/can-i-restrict-an-intermediate-ca-to-only-sign-client-certificates#:%7E:text=So%2C%20yes%20you%20can.) it says it would be possible, so I tried to create a test setup where I defined an extendedKeyUsage for the device/server-CA. The X509v3 extensions in the certs I created look like the following

Server/Device-CA:

```
X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE <-(yeah, forgot 'bout the path-length - hope this is not the problem)
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            51:0F:8C:55:88:4D:3E:25:DC:EC:6D:73:39:E4:7D:27:2E:AF:E4:2D
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:B3:6A:53:D9:9B:CF:74:69:B5:64:73:91:D7:18:92:30:E3:A7:7A:A6

        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
            TLS Web Server Authentication <--
```

Server/Device-CA -> Server-Cert

```
 X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:FALSE
        Netscape Cert Type: 
            SSL Server
        Netscape Comment: 
            OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            AD:BC:E0:73:50:AB:7F:BE:3C:43:71:4F:07:06:D8:3F:1A:38:81:4C
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:51:0F:8C:55:88:4D:3E:25:DC:EC:6D:73:39:E4:7D:27:2E:AF:E4:2D
            DirName:/C=XXX/ST=XXX/L=XX/O=XXX/OU=XXX/CN=XXX/emailAddress=XXX
            serial:10:00

        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication <--
```

Server/Device-CA -> Client-Cert

```
  X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:FALSE
        Netscape Cert Type: 
            SSL Client, S/MIME
        Netscape Comment: 
            OpenSSL Generated Client Certificate
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            AD:BC:E0:73:50:AB:7F:BE:3C:43:71:4F:07:06:D8:3F:1A:38:81:4C
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:51:0F:8C:55:88:4D:3E:25:DC:EC:6D:73:39:E4:7D:27:2E:AF:E4:2D

        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection <--
```

Anyway when I use openssl verify it says both certificates were valid. I hope you can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `openssl verify` does not know that the leaf certificate should be used as a client certificate. That's why it will not take the purpose of the certificates into account when validating the trust chain:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted middle.pem client.pem 
client.pem: OK
```

With an explicitly given purpose of sslclient it fails instead:

```
$ openssl verify -purpose sslclient -CAfile root.pem -untrusted middle.pem  client.pem 
CN = middle
error 26 at 1 depth lookup: unsupported certificate purpose
error client.pem: verification failed
```

Having a different intermediate certificate which has sslclient as purpose to it instead succeeds:

```
$ openssl verify -purpose sslclient -CAfile root.pem -untrusted alt-middle.pem  client.pem 
client.pem: OK
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Steffen. So, there is no command that automatically resolves and checks the purpose(s) in the chain?! Good to know then.

Comment: @laXta: In order to verify if a certificate fits a purpose one has to specify the purpose. It does not magically assume any specific purpose.